# Lambdas and functional interfaces with generic throw clauses

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

Consider this snippet of java 8 code:

```
public class Generics {
  public static <V, E extends Exception> V f(CheckedCallable1<V, E> callable) throws E {
    return callable.call();
  }
  public static <V, E extends Exception> V g(CheckedCallable2<V, E> callable) throws E {
    return callable.call();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(() -> 1);
    g(() -> 1);
  }
}

interface Callable<V> {
  V call() throws Exception;
}

interface CheckedCallable1<V, E extends Exception> {
  V call() throws E;
}

interface CheckedCallable2<V, E extends Exception> extends Callable<V> {
  @Override V call() throws E;
}
```

The lambda at the call to `f` compiles fine, whereas the lambda at the call to `g` does not compile, but rather gives this compile error:

```
Error:(10, 7) java: call() in <anonymous Generics$> cannot implement call() in CheckedCallable2
  overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception
```

Why is this?

It seems to me that both the `CheckedCallable1.call` and `CheckedCallable2.call` methods are equivalent: by the rules of type erasure, `V` becomes `Object` as it is unbounded, and `E` becomes `Exception`, as that's the upper type bound. So why does the compiler think the overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception?

Even disregarding type erasure, which is likely not relevant here because this is all happening at compile time, it still does not make sense to me: I don't see a reason why this pattern, if allowed, would result in, say, unsound java code.

So can someone enlighten me as to why this isn't allowed?

*Update:*

So I found something that's maybe even more interesting. Take the above file, change each occurrence of `Exception` to `IOException` and add throws clause to `main`. Compile works! Change back to `Exception`: compile breaks!

This compiles fine:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Generics {
  public static <V, E extends IOException> V f(CheckedCallable1<V, E> callable) throws E {
    return callable.call();
  }
  public static <V, E extends IOException> V g(CheckedCallable2<V, E> callable) throws E {
    return callable.call();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    f(() -> 1);
    g(() -> 1);
  }
}

interface Callable<V> {
  V call() throws IOException;
}

interface CheckedCallable1<V, E extends IOException> {
  V call() throws E;
}

interface CheckedCallable2<V, E extends IOException> extends Callable<V> {
  @Override V call() throws E;
}
```

At this point it's starting to look more and more like a java bug...

Comment: +1 also for making me aware of the generic exception type support in java 8

Comment: This question finally motivated me to get Java 8 working on my PC.  I just installed KeplerSR2, jdk1.8.0_05... and I'm getting a runtime exception, not a compile-time one, at the same spot:

 at Generics.main(Generics.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name&signature in class file Generics$$Lambda$2

What gives?

Comment: Interestingly, Eclipse's compiler emits no errors. No clue why.

Comment: @torquestomp Is that when compiling using Eclipse's compiler, or javac?

Comment: For reference, I'm using jdk1.8.0_05 as well, but in Intellij on Mac

Comment: @Tobi The Eclipse compiler.  I can reproduce poster's error with javac, so there's clearly an Eclipse bug here as well.

Comment: I'm getting the error too with javac (1.8.0_05, Eclipse was whatever the most recent integration build was for Luna). Last time something like this happened though the Eclipse developers asked me to file a bug with Oracle since the behavior seemed as expected, but it's been a few weeks and I haven't heard anything back. I'm curious if this will end up as another one of those...

Comment: When getting really weird errors, I wouldn't trust the Eclipse compiler (yet). Try to doublecheck it with other IDE or the javac compiler. Eclipse's Java 8 support seems to be rather buggy in edgecases.

Comment: This landed in the Java bug tracker: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8047338

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think that there is a rule forbidding this pattern. It’s rather likely you found a compiler bug.

It’s easy to show that this pattern does not result in unsound code by just writing down the equivalent inner class code of `g(() -> 1);`:

```
g(new CheckedCallable2<Integer, RuntimeException>() {
    public Integer call() {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

This compiles and runs without any problems, even under Java 6 (I assume it would even run on Java 5 but I had no JDK to test it) and there is no reason why it shouldn’t work when doing the same with a lambda. Writing down this code in Netbeans results even in the recommendation to convert it to a lambda.

There is also no runtime restriction which would forbid such a construct. Besides the fact that under the hood there are no exception rules enforced and everything relies on the compile-time checks, we can even prove that it would work if the compiler accepted our code by creating the code manually that the compiler would create:

```
CheckedCallable2<Integer,RuntimeException> c;
try
{
  MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
  c=(CheckedCallable2)
    LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "call",
      MethodType.methodType(CheckedCallable2.class),
      MethodType.methodType(Object.class),
      l.findStatic(Generics.class, "lambda$1", MethodType.methodType(int.class)),
      MethodType.methodType(Integer.class)).getTarget().invokeExact();
} catch(Throwable t) { throw new AssertionError(t); }
int i=g(c);
System.out.println(i);
// verify that the inheritance is sound:
Callable<Integer> x=c;
try { System.out.println(x.call()); }// throws Exception
catch(Exception ex) { throw new AssertionError(ex); }

…
static int lambda$1() { return 1; }// the synthetic method for ()->1
```

This code runs and produces `1` as expected, regardless of which `interface` we use to `call()`. Only the exceptions we have to catch differ. But as said, that’s a compile-time artifact.

Comment: Cool, thanks for trying this! I'll be filing a bug with Oracle.